# When I add a string array to the JSON data of an http put request, I get a 400 bad request error

Tags: python, httprequest, put

I'm trying to call a put request via python but keep getting a 400 bad request error.

Here's an example of what I'm basically trying to do:

```
array = ["abc", "def"]
myjson = {
  "array": array
}
data = json.dumps(myjson)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'data': data}
```

What's strange is that any other kind of data works fine. Number array, long strings, etc. Only the string array is not working for me.

I've tried different types of data, and not having any data at all. I've also tried empty arrays. Everything has worked except for string arrays.

I've also tried putting single or double quotes around each entry in the string array.

No matter what I do for string arrays, I always get a 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: Without knowing what the endpoint you're sending a PUT request is doing, I don't think this can be answered. `myjson` is technically valid JSON but the problem lies in the endpoint itself.

Comment: Thanks, it helps to have a second pair of eyes validate that the JSON looks fine and I'm not crazy.

Comment: You may still be crazy, it's possible the endpoint doesn't accept array of string for that field. Please provide the API documentation and someone should be able to confirm or deny.

Comment: Sorry friend, the API for the endpoint is an in-house solution for the company I work at.
That being said, you might be on to something. I should be able to confirm by the end of today.

Answer (score 0):

The code on the server did accept arrays, but only if it was smaller than the current array. It was weird. Instead of a put/post request changing the entry I needed to do a request to create a new entry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).